# how to update a column in sqlite db from pandas df using sqlachemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

i have a db sqlite where a table is stored. One column of this table called "Target" need to be updated. I have a method that provide me a new table (pandas df) with new values of column Target.
So, i initialized the table in sqlite like:

```
engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{databasePathName}')#, echo=True

metadata = MetaData()
predictedProbabilities = Table(
    tableName,
    metadata,
    Column("Date", Date),
    Column("Low", Float),
    Column("Open", Float),
    Column("Close", Float),
    Column("High", Float),
    Column("Target", Boolean),
    Column("PredictedProbabilities", Float),
    Column("ASSET", String),
    Column("INTERVAL", String),
    Column("QUANTILE", String),

)

predictedProbabilities.create(engine)
```

I iteratively compute some probabilities, and i am storing them. In order to populate this table, in every recursion i append a row, with the same structure clearly.

Now, every record is identified by the combinations of Date, ASSET, INTERVAL, QUANTILE, so those are the keys to use to make the update.

So, i decide to:

1. crate a temporary table
2. make the update with some query
3. drop temporary table

reseraching i arrived to a script that is something like that:

```
    
        with engine.connect() as conn:

            update_query = (
                update(predictedProbabilities)
                .where(
                    predictedProbabilities.c.Date == temp_table_name + '.Date'
                )
                .where(
                    predictedProbabilities.c.ASSET == temp_table_name + '.ASSET'
                )
                .where(
                    predictedProbabilities.c.INTERVAL == temp_table_name + '.INTERVAL'
                )
                .where(
                    predictedProbabilities.c.QUANTILE == temp_table_name + '.QUANTILE'
                )
                .values({'Target': self.data_store['target']})
            )

            """update_query = (
                    update(predictedProbabilities)
                    .where(
                        (predictedProbabilities.c.Date == temp_table_name.c.Date) &
                        (predictedProbabilities.c.ASSET == temp_table_name.c.ASSET) &
                        (predictedProbabilities.c.INTERVAL == temp_table_name.c.INTERVAL) &
                        (predictedProbabilities.c.QUANTILE == temp_table_name.c.QUANTILE)
                    )
                    .values({'Target': self.data_store['target']})
                )"""
            conn.execute(update_query)

            conn.execute(f'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {temp_table_name}')
```

but in console i receive an error like

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) unhashable type: 'Series'
[SQL: UPDATE "staging3_probabilities_DailyData" SET "Target"=? WHERE "staging3_probabilities_DailyData"."Date" = ? AND "staging3_probabilities_DailyData"."ASSET" = ? AND "staging3_probabilities_DailyData"."INTERVAL" = ? AND "staging3_probabilities_DailyData"."QUANTILE" = ?]
```

I hope everything is clear. Where am i wrong?

Comment: You might be thinking about this the wrong way. Typically when I'm trying to dynamically run SQL queries with python I write the code in such a way that I make a single connection and will dynamically build a string variable that has all the normal update statements associated with a SQL Update statement.

Comment: you mean something like that?  f"""UPDATE {tableName} 
                    SET Target = {temp_table_name}.target   
                    FROM {temp_table_name} "
                    WHERE {tableName}.Date = {temp_table_name}.Date 
                    AND {tableName}.ASSET = {temp_table_name}.ASSET
                    AND {tableName}.INTERVAL = {temp_table_name}.INTERVAL 
                    AND {tableName}.QUANTILE = {temp_table_name}.QUANTILE"""
                )

Comment: Exactly, this way you are basically just writing a dynamic SQL query instead of trying to do all sorts of fancy work with pandas/parameters within python.